# Resuming download with selected region in java

Tags: java, resume-download

I am trying to download specific region of a file using java. In the HTTP header request I am setting the 'Range' filed like as below.

```
 uc.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes= 0-8408468");
```

But, in the response I am getting the file with size of 8408469.

Why the returned file is always 1 byte higher than the expected value which is set through the HTTP request header?

Comment: How are you calculating the size of the file in the response ?

Comment: I am using `uc.getHeaderField("Content-Length")` to get the file size